# Format integer number with spaces jsf

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I have

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.intValue}">
```

On my page it looks like this: `1000000`.
How to format it with whitespaces to look it like this: `1 000 000`?

Comment: Take a look at `f:convertNumber`.

Comment: `1 000 000`? Why not format a number in a standard way - grouping a number?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just something like this should work:

```
<h:outputText value = "1000000" >
          <f:convertNumber type ="number" />
</h:outputText>
```